# Run Unix Command on remote host from Python without Password

Tags: unix, ssh, passwords, ssh-keys

Python uses `subprocess` command to call shell command. When I run the command on a different host it fails with authentication error.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["ssh","hostname","command"], shell=False,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, I couldn't see a post so I answered myself:

Assuming A as source host and B as remote host

enable ssh-keys

Login to remote host B and run the below command:
ssh-keygen -t rsa

Once the keys are generated, copy the contents of the below file from host B:
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Paste the contents of above file to the host A where python script is called:
.ssh/authorized_keys'

It should work after this setup! Any Unix command can be run from python to any remote host.